# ssh session exits when cd command fails

Tags: ssh, csh

I connect to a remote host using ssh. After connecting, if a cd command fails like below, my ssh connection exits right away. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
scott@mac % ssh remotehost
Last login: Tue Jun 14 17:15:44 2022 from mac

scott@remotehost % cd aaaaaa
aaaaaa: No such file or directory.
Connection to remotehost closed.
scott@mac %
```

shell in remote host is **csh**. Other commands like `cat`, `ls` etc. work fine even if I try them with a non existing filename.

Comment: sounds like your `csh` process dies (or gets ... deadified)!

Comment: can you try whether this also happens in a `csh` that you start manually? like: run `csh`, and in that `set prompt=kittens; cd aaaaaa`. If you see kittens asking for your input next, it doesn't happen to `csh` you spawn manually.